# Why 'list' object is not callable" bu use class

Tags: python, list

this is a about shape and I will provide coordinate ,but cannot store
here is my class code

```
 class point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class Rectangle():
     def __init__(self,left,right,position):
        self.left = left#point
        self.right = right#point
        self.position = position
```

I will us it build class list like:

```
rectangleArray = []
    point = list(input().split())//input data
    judge = point[0] //list[0] is judge shape so pop
    point.pop(0)
    point = [float(l) for l in point] //str convert float
    if(judge=='*'):
        break
    if(judge=='r'):
        temp = Rectangle(point(8.5,17.0),point(25.5,-8.5),0)
        temp = 
  Rectangle(point(point[0],point[1]),point(point[2],point[3]),number)
        rFinal = rFinal + 1
        rectangleArray.append(temp)// append to list
```

my error is:

```
   typeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-9ba8926badc6> in <module>()

     15         break
     16     if(judge=='r'):
---> 17         temp = Rectangle(point(8.5,17.0),point(25.5,-8.5),0)
     18         temp = Rectangle(point(point[0],point[1]),point(point[2],point[3]),number)
     19         rFinal = rFinal + 1

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Please tell me why !!
thank you

Comment: `point = list(input().split())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix your variable named `point`(which is `list`) with your class `point`.

You need to have different naming, use [upper-case for classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), e.g.

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

And then in code:

```
temp = Rectangle(Point(8.5,17.0),Point(25.5,-8.5),0)
temp = Rectangle(Point(point[0],point[1]),Point(point[2],point[3]),number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You define both a class `point` and a variable `point`. Because you're defining the variable `point` later, it shadows the class definition. Renaming the class to uppercase `Point` and calling `Rectangle(Point(8.5,17.0),Point(25.5,-8.5),0)` (see the uppercase) should solve the error.

Does this help?